# On clicking row in table view show map with that title in next view

Tags: ios, uitableview, mkmapview

I have a table view with titles of map retrieved from sqlite (latitude and longitude values also stored).

When clicking each title, I want map showing with that title in next view.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell1";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    }

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    MapColumns *mc=(MapColumns *)[appDelegate.outputArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text=mc.Title;
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
   return cell;

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    MapView *mv=[[MapView alloc]initWithNibName:@"MapView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mv animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In terms of setting the title for your map, you can set the `title` property of your MapView view controller when you instantiate it in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.  Get the value for your title by accessing your appDelegate's outputArray again, the same way you did in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

You will also need a way to pass the MapColumns object to your MapView view controller class.  To do this, create a property on your MapView class and assign your MapView object to that property before calling `pushViewController:`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MapView *mv = [[MapView alloc]initWithNibName:@"MapView" bundle:nil];

    MapColumns *mc = (MapColumns *)[appDelegate.outputArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    mv.title = mc.Title;

    mv.mapColumns = mc;  // set this property here you you can access the MapColumns object in your MapView view controller

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mv animated:YES];
}
```

Then in your MapView's `viewDidLoad` method, use the value of the `mapColumns` property that you have set to retrieve the latitude and longitude and configure your map appropriately.

If you don't know how to set up the map and show an annotation, you should start by reading Apple's [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH3-SW1).

Another useful tutorial for MapKit can be found [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial).

Comment: ,,,ya i configured map in next view and i confirmed the protocol..but here my problem is,as i already stored the latitude longitude values titles & subtitles in sqlite..i retrieved titles in a table.and in next view i created an mapview..when i clicked the title in table for ex bombay is the title,then in next view map would hav to show chennai location,by retrieving bombay latitude and longitude values which already i stored in database..pls help me as iam new to iphone development..thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Does you MapColumns object contain the latitude and longitude of the location you want to show on your map?

Comment: ya in mapcolumns class i created title,subtitle,latitude and longitude    which are columns in sqlite.i retrieved the title values as mapcolumns object.title;

Comment: here my problem is how to retrive the latitude and longitude values,which are stored as float values. pls suggest me the code where to write and what to write..pls consider my configured map also has an annotation..thanks in advance @jonkroll

Comment: Just updated my answer with some more info that might help you.